# Custom filter in Datatables does not load all data

Tags: jquery

This is also regarding DataTable. I have 2 custom filter so much alike. One works while one does not.

Take a look

**This one works**

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
    var age = parseFloat( data[12] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

    if (( isNaN( min )) ||
         ( min == age))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It loads all records at first and then does the filter on change.

**This one does not work**

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
var department = $('#department').val();
var dept = data[18]; // use data for the color column
if ( department == dept)//)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
);
```

Department dropdown value is 6 and so does the column[18]

It does the filtering but on default or if Choose nothing from the list (the default value which is '') it will now show the whole table data.

Anyone?

Reference: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24959/dropdown-instead-of-search-box

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Just for the others to be used as reference if they came accross this one also.

```
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
  var department = parseInt( $('#department').val(), 10 );
  var dept = parseFloat( data[18] ) || 0;//data[18]; // use data for the color column
  if (( isNaN( department )) ||
         ( department == dept))
      {
          return true;
      }
          return false;
  }
);
```

You have to parseint the value of the dropbox as well as parsefloat the value of the column.